# Temperature of the Sun via Stefan-Boltzmann law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, thermal-radiation

Let's calculate the sun's surface temperature using the Stefan-Bolztman law in the form

$$\langle w\rangle=\frac{4\sigma}{c}T^4$$

where $\sigma=5.67\cdot10^{-8}$ W$\cdot$m$^{-2}$/K$^4$ is the Stefan–Boltzmann constant, $\langle w\rangle$ is the timep-average of the energy density of the sun's radiation, and $T$ the temperature we are looking for.

I am given the value $I_0=1.35$ kW/m$^2$ of the solar constant (the power per unit area of the solar radiation on a panel oriented perpendicular to the sun's rays in the high Earth atmosphere).

---

From electromagnetism we know that the magnitude of the Poynting vector is simply $wc$ and the power per unit area $I_0$ is the time-average of the magntitude Poynting. Hence $I_0=\langle w\rangle c$.

We thus have $T=\left(\dfrac{I_0}{4\sigma}\right)^{1/4}=277$ K

which is obviously false as the real value is $5760$ K.

**What is wrong with this temperature calculation?**

Comment: σ = 5.670367(13)×10−8 W⋅$m^−2⋅K^−4$

Comment: it is m^-2, not m^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with this temperature calculation?

You have calculated the effective surface temperature of a ball with a radius of one astronomical unit that emits 1.35 kilowatts per square meter at its surface. The Sun is a ball with a radius of 695700 kilometers. At the surface of the Sun, your 1.35 kilowatts per square meter becomes 62.4 megawatts per square meter, resulting in a surface temperature of 5760 kelvins.

Answer (score 1):

Distance to the sun, or angle subtended by the sun?

The apparent diameter if the sun is half a degree, about 0.01 radian. The solid angle is then about π × 0.01^2/4. This is less than 4π (the whole sky) by a factor of $10^{-4}/16$. So the Sun is hotter than what you calculated by the fourth root of that: a factor 20.

Comment: Why does it matter.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou You calculated the temperature of the upper atmosphere of the Earth. (Because the Earth will radiate as much as it absorbs from the Sun.)